# jQuery SVG to access an item by id in a SVG image?

Tags: jquery, dom, svg

I am using jQuery SVG to import an SVG image and and want to fill a polygon with a color. However, I can't seem to find or access the element where `id="nose"`.

SVG extract:

```
<polygon id="nose" fill="#c00"
             points=" 127,101 132,100 137,99 144,101 143,105 135,110"/>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery SVG Basics</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.package-1.4.4/jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.package-1.4.4/jquery.svgdom.js"></script>

<style>
#map
{
    width:1280;
    height:1024px;
}

</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#map').svg();  
    var svg = $('#map').svg('get');
    svg.load('lion.svg',{onLoad: function(){ }});   
    $('nose', svg.root()).attr('fill', '#ccc');
    </script>
</html>
```